# How to smooth scroll to other page?

Tags: javascript, html, smooth-scrolling, sections

I have this JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.smooth-scroll').on('click', function(evt) {
    timber.closeDrawerMenu();
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate(
      { scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top},
      300
    );
  });
});
```

The smooth scroll works fine in the home page. but in other pages nothing happens since smooth scrolling is for sections in the home page

Thats html code:

```
<li>
    <a href="#home-features" class="smooth-scroll">Features</a>
</li>
```

I tried to

```
<li>
    <a href="homepage.com#home-features" class="smooth-scroll">Features</a>
</li>
```

and I didnt succeded.
How can I do it?

Comment: please post a jsfiddle or a code snippet reproducing your problem, see [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This is basically not possible.  The browser needs to draw a new window when it loads a new page, so there isn't anything to scroll smoothly to.  You'd need to switch to a SPA type architecture, with everything on one page, or else fake it (maybe have the "old" page animate a scroll past all the content, to a plain background, then have the "new" page load by animating a scroll in the same direction from that plain background to the content itself)

Comment: Wait if its not possible so lets make it without smooth scroll